# $(...).tabOverride is not a function when using tabOverride jquery api

Tags: jquery, laravel, api

I want to add tab inside textarea. I wanted to use API. So when I use tabOverride Jquery API. It is showing me $(...).tabOverride is not a function.I am using laravel for this project. Here is how my share layout look like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        @yield('title')
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')

    {{ Html::script('js/jquery-3.3.1.js') }}
    {{ Html::script('js/jquery.taboverride.min.js') }}

    <script>
        $('textarea').tabOverride(true);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From [the source page](https://github.com/wjbryant/jquery.taboverride) *The latest version of the plugin requires: Tab Override v4.0.0+* but you are not loading that here

Comment: No, `jquery.taboverride.min.js` is the jQuery wrapper for `taboverride.js` which **also needs to be included**

Comment: Thank You very much, Sir it works.Really thank you...